# Запросы PHP-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет,такой вопрос.Есть Бд с 1 таблицей и 5 столбцами, и есть 2 страницы.

[image: БД]

вот Index стр

```
<? $db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'figures';
$db_username = 'root';



$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Не найдено соединение: ".mysql_error());


mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Не найдена бд: ".mysql_error());




echo "<form method='post' action='obj.php'><select name='id'>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {

  $sql = mysql_query("select * from `figures` where `id`='".$i.
    "' order by `about Obj`");
  while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<option value='".$s['id'].
    "'>".$s['about Obj'].
    "</option>";


  }
  $sec = $s['id'];
  echo "<br>";

}

echo "</select>
                            <input type='submit' name='action' value='Выбрать'>

                            </form>"; 

?>
```

вот страница принимающая код

```
   $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Не найдено соединение: " . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Не найдена бд: " . mysql_error());  

 $sec1=$_POST['sec'];
if(isset ($_POST['action'])){

$sql=mysql_query("select * from `figures` where `id`='".$sec1."'");
while ($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $data1['obj'];
    }
 }
```

мне нужно что бы выбраному id передавал значение из колонки obj и записывал в переменнуюю,но что то не получается ,скажите опытным глазом что не так и что исправить.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `но что то не получается` - что конкретно? ошибки выдает? Или записывает сразу 1000 строк или запирается в ванной и тратит напрасно горячую воду?

Comment: проверь на всякий if isset $_POST['sec'] && !empty $_POST['sec']

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто не передает значение obj соответсвующего id,а 1 до 1000 это я простно не помню функцию которая до конца бд перебирает))

Comment: по моему проблема в несоотвествии $_POST. у вас форма с элементом name='id', а вы принимаете $_POST['sec']

Comment: @Jean-Claude  то есть так ? $sec1=$_POST['id']

Comment: print_r($_POST) делайте всегда когда не уверены что там есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы заполняете `select` с именем `id`

> `<select name='id'>`

А читаете из переменной `sec`

> `$sec1=$_POST['sec'];`

Синхронизируйте оба имени

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov то есть так ? $sec1=$_POST['id'];

Comment: @MichaelBocharov да

Comment: все передается но только приписывается id в конце ,как убрать?